# Why am I not able to parse JSON correctly with AWS SDK in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I am using Laravel 5.5 with the AWS SDK for laravel (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel).

I'm trying to do a simple request to establish that I'm connecting correctly.  I believe I have my credentials all set and nothing points to that as an error.

Here is the function in my laravel controller that is being called:

```
 public function testData(Request $request) {
    $sdk = new Sdk([
        'endpoint'   => 'http://localhost:80',
        'region'   => 'us-east-1',
        'version'  => 'latest'
    ]);

    $dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
    $marshaler = new Marshaler();

    $tableName = 'funTalkDataStorage';

    $params = [
        'TableName' => $tableName
    ];

    try {
        $result = $dynamodb->query($params);

    } catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
        echo "Unable to query:\n";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

The table 'funTalkDataStorage' does exist out on AWS already where there are two records already.

The thing that I'm not understanding is why I'm getting the following error from Laravel:

Aws \ Api \ Parser \ Exception \ ParserException
Error parsing JSON: Syntax error

being thrown by :

aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Api\Parser\PayloadParserTrait.php

The error is originating from the line in my code:

```
$result = $dynamodb->query($params);
```

I've been digging through the sdk and searching the web and I'm just not getting where the issue is.  Any help would be marvalous!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  My issue was that i was using port 80.  It should have been port 8000.